# Custom Header / Footer options in Sharepoint (WSS 3 IE Browser Only)

Tags: wss-3.0, printing

I have been searching for several weeks now how best to approach something we have been asked to come up with and it seems that it should be simple but I have yet to find a suitable answer. I want to print from Sharepoint WSS 3 with the ability to add a custom header and footer without the default header and footer from IE. I had hoped that there would be a way to use C# code to do this, but I am just not finding anything that points me in the right direction. Is it possible to build a print function that will do this and if so, please point me to any examples that may be available.

Answer (score 1):

I am nearly positive that this cannot be done in IE without the user altering the Page Setup.  You may want to consider using a "Printable Version" link that simply redirects the user to a dynamically created PDF version of the content.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want one header and footer to display when someone is browsing a page, but you want a different header and footer to display when printing the page.

For this, I would recommend using CSS media types.  This will instruct the browser to use one stylesheet when viewing and a different stylesheet when printing.  Here is some more information:  http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

```
Tim
```

Comment: Will these templates overwrite IE print templates. I thought that you would still get the annoying IE header/footer when using these. I will look into this in more depth. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS and Javascript you can grab the contents of a content container and send it to a new window with the additional content (header/footer) added.  You should be able to build this into a Web Part that is deployed to the pages that require it.

Comment: I did look at this as an option, but it still prints through IE right?

Comment: This method would print through IE

Comment: What I meant was the default header and footer of IE would still show up on the print out and the requirement is that they do not.

Comment: In the window.open() call you can control what gets displayed and what does not.  You can turn off the toolbars, URL, etc.  http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Comment: I know how to do that part and thanks for the link to that. I think what I am missing is how this will allow the printing of my custom header/footer info without printing the IE header/footer info like the url and page x of y in our intranet. You are being extremely helpful which I do appreciate.